# Is it possible to add extra amount on authorized amount on PayPal in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, paypal, paypal-express, paypal-payments-pro

Is there any way to add extra amount or additional charge in authorized payment on Paypal account?

Currently, we are not using the shipping method in Magento 2 order and we are using Paypal payment method and we want to add the additional amount on the authorized amount in Paypal for the shipping method after the order placed.

So can you please let me know how can I achieve this functionality?

Help would be appreciated.